# Reorder table columns using Drag and Drop with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drag-and-drop

I want to allow the user to reorder the columns in the table by dragging and dropping them. I am using **jquery.dragtable.js** to allow drag and drop. It`s working fine. Now I want to store the table order after drag and drop on the client-side and restore the state onload.

Here is my HTML Code:

```
<table id="tblReg" class="table table-bordered">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>#</th>
            <th>First Name</th>
            <th>Last Name</th>
            <th>Username</th>
            <th>Password</th>
            <th>Email</th>
            <th>Phone</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th>1</th>
            <td>Mark</td>
            <td>Otto</td>
            <td>@mdo</td>
            <td>545trt574</td>
            <td>Na@email.com</td>
            <td>7788994320</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>2</th>
            <td>Jacob</td>
            <td>Thornton</td>
            <td>@fat</td>
            <td>yffft5456</td>
            <td>Na@email.com</td>
            <td>7788994320</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>3</th>
            <td>Larry</td>
            <td>the Bird</td>
            <td>@twitter</td>
            <td>fgfhgf444</td>
            <td>Na@email.com</td>
            <td>7788994320</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>4</th>
            <td>Rima</td>
            <td>the Bird</td>
            <td>@twitter</td>
            <td>jjk8899</td>
            <td>Na@email.com</td>
            <td>7788994320</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>5</th>
            <td>Sundar</td>
            <td>the Bird</td>
            <td>@twitter</td>
            <td>76767687hjh</td>
            <td>Na@email.com</td>
            <td>7788994320</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

<a href="#" class="order">Get Table Order</a>
<p class="porder"></p>
```

Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#tblReg').each(function(){
        $(this).dragtable({
            placeholder: 'dragtable-col-placeholder',
            items: 'thead th:not( .notdraggable ):not( :has( .dragtable-drag-handle ) ), .dragtable-drag-handle',
            appendTarget: $(this).parent(),
            scroll: true
        });
    });
    $('a.order').click(function(){
        console.log($('#tblReg').dragtable('order'));
        var curOrder = $('#tblReg').dragtable('order');
        $('.porder').text(curOrder);
        return false;
    });
});
```

Plugin Refer: https://github.com/akottr/dragtable

The allow to provide get the table order as follows:

```
["#", "First Name", "Last Name", "Username", "Password", "Email", "Phone"]
```

Now I want to store this in client side (LocalStorage / Cookies) and reorder OnLoad as per save data.

How to do this? I'm new in jquery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done ! Please check if any mistake.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //localStorage.clear();
    var tblReg  = $('#tblReg').attr('id');
    var tblRegMaster = $('#tblRegMaster').attr('id');

    processDnD(tblReg);
    processDnD(tblRegMaster);

});


function processDnD(cuTable){
    var tblName = cuTable;
    $('#'+cuTable).find('th').each(function() {
        var ctxt = $(this).text();
        if(ctxt == 'First Name'){
            $(this).attr('id','firstName-'+tblName);
        }else if(ctxt == 'Password'){
            $(this).attr('id','password'+tblName);
        }else if(ctxt == 'Email'){
            $(this).attr('id','iemail'+tblName);
        }else if(ctxt == 'Username'){
            $(this).attr('id','userName'+tblName);
        }else if(ctxt == 'Last Name'){
            $(this).attr('id','lastName'+tblName);
        }else if(ctxt == '#'){
            $(this).attr('id','slNo'+tblName);
        }else if(ctxt == 'Phone'){
            $(this).attr('id','phone'+tblName);
        }else if(ctxt == 'PO Number'){
            $(this).attr('id','pono'+tblName);
        }else if(ctxt == 'Shipper'){
            $(this).attr('id','shipperName'+tblName);
        }else if(ctxt == 'Status'){
            $(this).attr('id','cuStatus'+tblName);
        }else if(ctxt == 'Booking Line'){
            $(this).attr('id','BookingLine'+tblName);
        }else if(ctxt == 'Access Mode'){
            $(this).attr('id','AccessMode'+tblName);
        }else if(ctxt == 'Container No'){
            $(this).attr('id','ContainerNo'+tblName);
        }
    })

    $('#'+cuTable).dragtable({ 
        persistState: function(table) { 
        if (!window.localStorage) return; 
            var ss = window.localStorage; 
            table.el.find('th').each(function(i) { 
            if(this.id != '') {table.sortOrder[this.id]=i;} 
        }); 
        ss.setItem('setTableOrder-'+tblName, JSON.stringify(table.sortOrder)); 
        }, 
        restoreState: eval('(' + window.localStorage.getItem('setTableOrder-'+tblName) + ')') 
    });

    $('#'+cuTable).each(function(){
        $(this).dragtable({
            placeholder: 'dragtable-col-placeholder',
            items: 'thead th:not(.notdraggable):not(:has(.dragtable-drag-handle)), .dragtable-drag-handle',
            appendTarget: $(this).parent(),
            scroll: true
        })
    }); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code, Its working fine.

Columns ordering set into **sessionStorage** after drag-n-drop and then refresh your page. You will see columns order change. 
[image]

Ordering records in array format, You can see in console:
[image]

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Reorder</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//rawgithub.com/akottr/dragtable/master/dragtable.css" />
</head>
<body>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
      <table id="tblReg" class="table table-bordered">
        <thead>
          <tr class="active">
            <th id="number">#</th>
            <th id="fname">First Name</th>
            <th id="lname">Last Name</th>
            <th id="uname">Username</th>
            <th id="pass">Password</th>
            <th id="email">Email</th>
            <th id="phone">Phone</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <th>1</th>
            <td>Mark</td>
            <td>Otto</td>
            <td>@mdo</td>
            <td>545trt574</td>
            <td>Na@email.com</td>
            <td>7788994320</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th>2</th>
            <td>Jacob</td>
            <td>Thornton</td>
            <td>@fat</td>
            <td>yffft5456</td>
            <td>Na@email.com</td>
            <td>7788994320</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th>3</th>
            <td>Larry</td>
            <td>the Bird</td>
            <td>@twitter</td>
            <td>fgfhgf444</td>
            <td>Na@email.com</td>
            <td>7788994320</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th>4</th>
            <td>Rima</td>
            <td>the Bird</td>
            <td>@twitter</td>
            <td>jjk8899</td>
            <td>Na@email.com</td>
            <td>7788994320</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th>5</th>
            <td>Sundar</td>
            <td>the Bird</td>
            <td>@twitter</td>
            <td>76767687hjh</td>
            <td>Na@email.com</td>
            <td>7788994320</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-info order">Get Table Order</a>
      <p class="porder"></p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>




<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="//rawgithub.com/akottr/dragtable/master/jquery.dragtable.js"></script>


<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  // this code for sessionStorage
  $('#tblReg').dragtable({ 
    persistState: function(table) { 
      if (!window.sessionStorage) return; 
      var ss = window.sessionStorage; 
      table.el.find('th').each(function(i) { 
        if(this.id != '') {table.sortOrder[this.id]=i;} 
      }); 
      ss.setItem('tableorder', JSON.stringify(table.sortOrder)); 
    }, 
    restoreState: eval('(' + window.sessionStorage.getItem('tableorder') + ')') 
  });

  // this code for each th drag and drop 
  $('#tblReg').each(function(){
    $(this).dragtable({
      placeholder: 'dragtable-col-placeholder',
      items: 'thead th:not(.notdraggable):not(:has(.dragtable-drag-handle)), .dragtable-drag-handle',
      appendTarget: $(this).parent(),
      scroll: true
    });
  });

  // Click and then you see ordering of (th) in console.
  $('a.order').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var order_array = [];
    $('#tblReg').dragtable().find('thead th').each(function(i,v){
      order_array.push($(v).text());
    });
    console.log(order_array);
    $('.porder').text(order_array);
  }); 

}); 
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: but after page refresh table order not change as per console array

Comment: and I want to use localStorage instead of sessionStorage @ Raeesh

Comment: Console array will change after click on "Get Table Order" button. And I am try to solve with localStorage @sandy

Answer (score 0):

Try this code for columns order store in **localStorage**.

[image]

```
  //For localstorage
  $('#tblReg').dragtable({ 
    persistState: function(table) { 
      if (!window.localStorage) return; 
      var ss = window.localStorage; 
      table.el.find('th').each(function(i) { 
        if(this.id != '') {table.sortOrder[this.id]=i;} 
      }); 
      ss.setItem('tableorder', JSON.stringify(table.sortOrder));
     $('a.order').trigger('click');//When drop the column then button will trigger 
    }, 
    restoreState: eval('(' + window.localStorage.getItem('tableorder') + ')') 
  });
```

Comment: Here you also use <th> ID and active class for <tr> But It's not need to add <th> ID because my table is dynamically generate.

Comment: Its working fine with <td> id. but my table dynamically generate, what's why I need without td id @Raeesh

Comment: Thanks @sandy. Because of there is need for unique identity in localStorage for set and get the records. Sounds good for your need, I am trying to solve this without <th> id after achieve will post here...

Comment: Hi Raeesh I have create a code for dynamic ID generate and its working fine. But when I add one or more table its not working.

Comment: Hi @JargoViet. Ok If you want multiple table to store order in localStorage so you will need different **table id** and **th id** and also different **setItem name** and after  initialize that **ids into JavaScript** code. Thanks

Comment: Raeesh@ jump into this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40271085/jquery-table-columns-drag-and-drop-with-re-order?noredirect=1#comment67802999_40271085