# jquery table columns Drag and Drop with re-order

Tags: javascript, jquery, drag-and-drop

I want to allow the user to reorder the columns in the table by dragging and dropping them. I am using jquery.dragtable.js to allow drag and drop and save the order after drag and drop even reload the page. Here I used localStorage to store table order as option provide by plugin JS. Its working with only a single table. In More than one table with name column header, its not working.
Actually, It's overwrite the previous localStorage variable with another table order value.

HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Table Reorder</title>
<script src="jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.dragtable.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="dragtable.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <table id="tblReg" class="table table-bordered">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>#</th>
                <th>First Name</th>
                <th>Last Name</th>
                <th>Username</th>
                <th>Password</th>
                <th>Email</th>
                <th>Phone</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody class="sort">
            <tr>
                <th>1</th>
                <td>Mark</td>
                <td>Otto</td>
                <td>@mdo</td>
                <td>545trt574</td>
                <td>Na@email.com</td>
                <td>7788994320</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>2</th>
                <td>Jacob</td>
                <td>Thornton</td>
                <td>@fat</td>
                <td>yffft5456</td>
                <td>Na@email.com</td>
                <td>7788994320</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>3</th>
                <td>Larry</td>
                <td>the Bird</td>
                <td>@twitter</td>
                <td>fgfhgf444</td>
                <td>Na@email.com</td>
                <td>7788994320</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>4</th>
                <td>Rima</td>
                <td>the Bird</td>
                <td>@twitter</td>
                <td>jjk8899</td>
                <td>Na@email.com</td>
                <td>7788994320</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>5</th>
                <td>Sundar</td>
                <td>the Bird</td>
                <td>@twitter</td>
                <td>76767687hjh</td>
                <td>na@email.com</td>
                <td>7788994320</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>

    <hr>

    <table id="tblRegMaster" class="table table-bordered">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>#</th>
                <th>First Name</th>
                <th>Last Name</th>
                <th>Username</th>
                <th>Password</th>
                <th>Email</th>
                <th>Phone</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody class="sort">
            <tr>
                <th>1</th>
                <td>Mark</td>
                <td>Otto</td>
                <td>@mdo</td>
                <td>545trt574</td>
                <td>Na@email.com</td>
                <td>7788994320</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>2</th>
                <td>Jacob</td>
                <td>Thornton</td>
                <td>@fat</td>
                <td>yffft5456</td>
                <td>Na@email.com</td>
                <td>7788994320</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>3</th>
                <td>Larry</td>
                <td>the Bird</td>
                <td>@twitter</td>
                <td>fgfhgf444</td>
                <td>Na@email.com</td>
                <td>7788994320</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>4</th>
                <td>Rima</td>
                <td>the Bird</td>
                <td>@twitter</td>
                <td>jjk8899</td>
                <td>Na@email.com</td>
                <td>7788994320</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>5</th>
                <td>Sundar</td>
                <td>the Bird</td>
                <td>@twitter</td>
                <td>76767687hjh</td>
                <td>na@email.com</td>
                <td>7788994320</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Jquery -

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var tblReg  = $('#tblReg').attr('id');
    var tblRegMaster = $('#tblRegMaster').attr('id');

    processDnD(tblReg);
    processDnD(tblRegMaster);

});


function processDnD(cuTable){
    $('#'+cuTable).find('th').each(function() {
        var ctxt = $(this).text();
        if(ctxt == 'First Name'){
            $(this).attr('id','firstName');
        }else if(ctxt == 'Password'){
            $(this).attr('id','password');
        }else if(ctxt == 'Email'){
            $(this).attr('id','iemail');
        }else if(ctxt == 'Username'){
            $(this).attr('id','Username');
        }else if(ctxt == 'Last Name'){
            $(this).attr('id','lastName');
        }else if(ctxt == '#'){
            $(this).attr('id','slNo');
        }else if(ctxt == 'Phone'){
            $(this).attr('id','phone');
        }       
    })

    $('#'+cuTable).dragtable({ 
        persistState: function(table) { 
        if (!window.localStorage) return; 
            var ss = window.localStorage; 
            table.el.find('th').each(function(i) { 
            if(this.id != '') {table.sortOrder[this.id]=i;} 
        }); 
        ss.setItem('setTableOrder', JSON.stringify(table.sortOrder)); 
        }, 
        restoreState: eval('(' + window.localStorage.getItem('setTableOrder') + ')') 
    });

    $('#'+cuTable).each(function(){
        $(this).dragtable({
            placeholder: 'dragtable-col-placeholder',
            items: 'thead th:not(.notdraggable):not(:has(.dragtable-drag-handle)), .dragtable-drag-handle',
            appendTarget: $(this).parent(),
            scroll: true
        })
    }); 
}
```

I would like to work reoder multipule table. Please suggest any solution. Thanks

Plugin Refer: https://github.com/akottr/dragtable

Comment: jquery dragtable can work with two tables (and your code seems to work correct). Maybe you want that the reordering of the first table will also change the order of the second table?

Comment: it's working perfectly! check this http://codepen.io/mozzi/pen/gwyZrd

Comment: yes also change the order of the second or more table@ dekel

Comment: yes mina drag and drop working perfectly. Not Reorder after page re load @ Mina

Comment: if it's not possible, then provide me a solution for multiple table Drag and Drop with reorder @Dekel

Comment: i found columns in the same order they were before closing the tab! both tables.

Comment: As per your live code just move a column in last table and refresh ta page. the last order applyed in first table@Mina

Comment: just move a column and view object in window.localStorage to what actelly happen

Comment: Hi @JargoViet I have solved your problem. check this **https://jsfiddle.net/raeeshalam/rn8sxxba/** . Drag-n-Drop both table column and then reload the page. I hope this snippet help you.

Answer (score 1):

I have solved this problem you can check on jsFiddle from **below url**. I hope this snippet help you.

```
jsfiddle.net/raeeshalam/rn8sxxba
```